# Help with RewriteRules

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Would it be possible to rewrite these:

```
news.php?id=1004
news.php?action=add
news.php?action=edit&newsid=1004
```

to

```
news/1004
news/add
news/edit/1004
```

With only one RewriteRule ?

Comment: Which set of URLs will the client be requesting? I'm assuming the nicer ones (news/1004, news/add, news/edit/1004) rather than the uglier ones (news.php?id=1004).

Comment: Why should it be with **only one** Rewriterule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about one rule, but you should be okay with something like this to reference the id number or action.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule news/([0-9]+)$ news.php?id=$1
  RewriteRule news/add$ news.php?action=add
  RewriteRule news/edit/([0-9]+)$ news.php?action=edit&newsid=$1
</IfModule>
```

This might be condenseable with something like:

```
# Rewrite news/actionterm/idnum -> news.php?action=actionterm&id=idnum    
RewriteRule news/([^/])/([0-9]+) news.php?action=$1&id=$2
```

Assuming the parameter for viewing viewing and editing can both be id= instead of id= and newsid=.